# toggle selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, stateless, stateful

In the stateful component I have the following code:

```
const handleUserClick = (username, usermemo, userSelected) => {
    const isUsername = userName === username ? "Select a user" : username;
    const isUsermemo = userMemo === usermemo ? null : usermemo;
    setUserName(isUsername);
    setUserMemo(isUsermemo);
    setSelectedUser(userSelected);
  };
```

In the stateless component, I have the following code:

```
const selectUserClick = ({ target }) => {
    let selectedUserIndex = USERS_DATA[target.value];
    let username = `${selectedUserIndex.first_name} ${selectedUserIndex.last_name} 
                  - ${selectedUserIndex.occupation}`;
    let usermemo = `"${selectedUserIndex.catch_phrase}"`;

    userSelected = target.classList.toggle("selected");

    getUser(username, usermemo, userSelected);`enter code here`
  };
```

Comment: its because you are toggling the selected state of current target that is clicked and not doing anything to the previously selected.

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb, hi thank for your advise. How would I do this then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the User.js to below

The className is dynamically set based on which user is selected

Referlink - [Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-framework-n8sdf?file=/src/User.js)

```js
import React from "react";
import { USERS_DATA } from "./data.js";

export default function User({ getUser, userSelected }) {
  const selectUserClick = ({ target }) => {
    let selectedUserIndex = USERS_DATA[target.value];
    let username = `${selectedUserIndex.first_name} ${selectedUserIndex.last_name} 
                      - ${selectedUserIndex.occupation}`;
    let usermemo = `"${selectedUserIndex.catch_phrase}"`;

    // userSelected = target.classList.toggle("selected");

    getUser(username, usermemo, selectedUserIndex);
  };

  return (
    <div className="users-container">
      <ul>
        {USERS_DATA.map((user, index) => (
          <li
            key={index}
            value={user.id - 1}
            onClick={selectUserClick}
            className={`users ${
              userSelected && user.id === userSelected.id ? "selected" : ""
            }`}
          >
            {user.user_name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: for more readability would change  ` className={`${userSelected && user.id === userSelected.id ? "users selected" : "users"}`}  ` (back tick is overrided as code here :))

Answer (score 0):

In your case something like this would work as long as you didn't need to select more than one option at a time. Run a function that gets all the users with a class name of 'selected' attached to them and toggle them off before making a new selection.

```
const selectUserClick = ({ target }) => {
  resetHighlights();

  let selectedUserIndex = USERS_DATA[target.value];
  let username = `${selectedUserIndex.first_name} ${selectedUserIndex.last_name} - ${selectedUserIndex.occupation}`;
  let usermemo = `"${selectedUserIndex.catch_phrase}"`;

  userSelected = target.classList.toggle("selected");

  getUser(username, usermemo, userSelected);
};

function resetHighlights() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("users");

  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    if (arr[x].classList.contains("selected")) {
      arr[x].classList.toggle("selected");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to do is as :

I have added as comments in the code for brief

```js
export default function User({
  getUser,
  userSelected
}) {
  const selectUserClick = ({
    target
  }) => {
    let selectedUserIndex = USERS_DATA[target.value];
    let username = `${selectedUserIndex.first_name} ${selectedUserIndex.last_name} 
                      - ${selectedUserIndex.occupation}`;
    let usermemo = `"${selectedUserIndex.catch_phrase}"`;

    // get all li elements of selected users
    let usersEl = document.getElementsByClassName("users selected");
    let usersList = [...usersEl];

    // assigns exisiting class to toggled class beforre selection
    usersList.forEach((element) => {
      element.className = "users";
    });

    // style only current selected el
    userSelected = target.classList.toggle("selected");

    getUser(username, usermemo, userSelected);
  };
```

Comment: no worries , there could be much efficient way as the above answer :)